# How Unique Are MAC Addresses

Tags: embedded, ethernet, mac-address

I know different devices have different MAC Addresses to distinguish them.  My question is about an embedded board.  For instance my board has two Ethernet ports that each have their individual MAC Address.  Will these MAC Addresses be the same for the Ethernet ports on each board that is made?  So locally to the system/board will the MAC Address for Ethernet port 1 be the same from board to board?

Comment: When devices are manufactured properly, MAC addresses are *globally unique*.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Just to make sure that I understand you.  If we take an Raspberry PI, each Ethernet port on every Raspberry PI should have the same MAC Address?  Edit* Misread what you posted, I understand now

Comment: Absolutely not. Every Ethernet adapter ever made should have a unique MAC address, not found on any Ethernet adapter anywhere else on the planet.

Comment: Note that even though each port has a unique address, most systems allow overriding the configured MAC address from the OS. In *nix, this is done with the `ifconfig` command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each port should have globally unique MAC address, however usually developers board has no MAC set initially, and everybody set's what he wants. Which works well until two same MAC's appears in one physical network.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is only addresses without the locally administered bit set which are guaranteed to be unique.  Those with that bit set could be made by whatever method someone chose, so there is a potential for collision.

Answer (score 2):

Mac's are designed to be unique. The beginning segments identify the manufacturer the trailing numbers are unique based on manufacturer construction. This is thanks to the IEEE standards!